# Error defining a struct in Julia: syntax: invalid type signature around REPL[2]:1

Tags: julia

I am trying to define a struct in Julia as follows:

```
julia> struct
           myName::String
       end
ERROR: syntax: invalid type signature around REPL[2]:1
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[2]:1
```

however I am getting the error shown above. Any suggestions to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, the issue is the `struct` requires a name which I did not specific. I needed to do something like this:

```
julia> struct person
           myName::String
       end
```

which resolves the issue.